# Use text file as a counter

Tags: batch-file

I would like to increase the value read from a text file by one, `1`. Then when it reaches a specific value, do something and reset the value in the text file to zero, `0`.

**Edit**

Here's my batch file:

```bat
set /p count=<c:\count.txt
set /a count+=1
echo.%count%>c:\count.txt
if %count%==5 (
    echo.%count%>c:\count.txt
)
exit
```

Comment: Please make a better attempt at a question, perhaps by including the batch file code you have so far and maybe pre and post text file examples.

Comment: set /p count=<c:\count.txt
set /a count+=1
echo.%count%>c:\count.txt
if %count%==5 (

echo.%count%>c:\count.txt
)
exit

Comment: Delete the post!

Comment: You can delete your own post. by selecting the delete button at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

some minor points only:
- changed syntax for writing to file, because `echo 2>file` doesn't write `2` to the file, but writes Erroroutput from `echo`(which is empty)
- used `geq` instead of `==` (optional, just better logic and safer)
- writing `0` instead of `%count%` if count is equal/greater `5`

```
set /p count=<c:\count.txt
set /a count+=1
>c:\count.txt echo.%count%
if %count% geq 5 (
    >c:\count.txt echo.0
    echo reached five. Doing something.
)
exit
```